# modify display format of data in php

Tags: php, csv

I have a csv file wich contain 3 row and 3 column ( the name of column are : firstname , lastname and adress

I developed a php script which displayed all data from this file

```
<?php
ini_set('display_errors',1);
 error_reporting(E_ALL);

//Fichier CSV à parser

$fichier = '/home/test.csv';
//On vérifie que le fichier existe bien :)

if (file_exists($fichier))
{
//On l'ouvre en mode "read only"
$fp = fopen($fichier, 'r');
//Tant que l'on n'a pas finit de lire le fichier
while (!feof($fp)){
//On lit les 4096 caractères de la ligne
$ligne = fgets($fp,4096);
/* On met dans un tableau toutes les données, séparées par des points virgules */
$liste = explode(';',$ligne);
/* On crée une colonne contenant les données pour chacune d'entre elles en parsant le tableau */
foreach($liste as $element)
{

   if (trim($element)!=null)
   {
echo $element;
echo "</br>";

   }

}

}

//On ferme le fichier

fclose($fp);
}
else
echo "Fichier introuvable !";


?>
```

my goal is to display the result in this format :

firstname : ... lastname ... adress ...

firstname : ... lastname ... adress ...

firstname : ... lastname ... adress ...

I think that I should modify this part in my code :

```
foreach($liste as $element)
    {

       if (trim($element)!=null)
       {
    echo $element;
    echo "</br>";

       }

    }
```

Comment: Why not use fgetcsv() rather than fgets() and then exploding.... when PHP has built-in functions for this, use them

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
 <?php
    ini_set('display_errors',1);
     error_reporting(E_ALL);

    //Fichier CSV à parser

    $fichier = '/home/test.csv';
    //On vérifie que le fichier existe bien :)

    if (file_exists($fichier))
    {
    //On l'ouvre en mode "read only"
    $fp = fopen($fichier, 'r');
    //Tant que l'on n'a pas finit de lire le fichier
    while (!feof($fp)){
    //On lit les 4096 caractères de la ligne
    $ligne = fgets($fp,4096);
    /* On met dans un tableau toutes les données, séparées par des points virgules */
    $liste = explode(';',$ligne);
    /* On crée une colonne contenant les données pour chacune d'entre elles en parsant le tableau */
    if(trim($liste[0])!=null)
    echo " firstname " . $liste[0];
    if(trim($liste[1])!=null)
    echo " lastname" .  $liste[1];
   if(trim($liste[2])!=null)
    echo " address" .  $liste[2];
    echo "<br/>";
       }

    }
```

Comment: in my previous code I use this test : if (trim($element)!=null)  so we should add a test in the new code

Answer (score 0):

i try something like this . maybe it will help you.

```
while (!feof($fp))
{
    $ligne = fgets($fp,4096);
    $liste = explode(';',$ligne);

    if($liste[0] != "firstname" && $liste[1] != "lastname" && $liste[2] != "address")
    {
        echo " <strong>firstname</strong> : " . $liste[0];
        echo " <strong>lastname</strong> : " .  $liste[1];
        echo " <strong>address</strong> : " .  $liste[2];
        echo "<br/>";
    }   
}
```